# Deploy PAM system-auth file from Configuration Server (Spacewalk)

Tags: centos, authentication, pam

I have my pam.d system-auth file set up correctly on a laptop to set password complexity requirements. If the contents of the file are copied directly into the /etc/pam.d/system-auth location (or the /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac if the symlink is set up) on another laptop, it works there, too.

However, I am trying to use the Spacewalk configuration file deployment option to deploy to these systems so I can be sure the policy isn't altered at a later time. When the file is copied to the location, it won't allow any password changes. It just says permission denied.

I verified that the read/write access is correct, and all SELinux contexts are set correctly. I feel like there is a permission or account restriction here that I am not considering.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.

I had to deploy the file with different selinux contexts than anticipated. I checked the contexts of the original file prior to deployment using:

> ls -Z

Then, I used those specific options and had success.

If anyone else ever runs into this issue, I hope that this helps.